# using fscanf to read in a integer from a file

Tags: c

gcc 4.4.4 c89

I have the following file that contains name, age, and gender. I am trying to read in the age.

```
"Bloggs, Joe" 34 M
```

I can open the file successfully:

```
fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
if(fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file [ %s ]\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
}
```

And I try and read in the age ( 34 ).

```
int age = 0;
int result = 0;
result = fscanf(fp, "%d", &age);
```

However, when I try and print the outcome, I always get a zero for age and result.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've done nothing to skip across the name, so it's looking at that text, attempting to convert it to an int and failing, so the return value is 0 (0 conversions succeeded) and the value that was in the variable remains unchanged. You need to add code to skip across the name, *then* read the age:

```
fscanf(fp, "%*c%*[^\"]\" %d", &age);
```

The initial `"%c"` reads the initial quote. The `"%[^\"]\"` reads characters up to (and including) the next quote. In both cases, the "*" means that value will be read but not stored anywhere. After that, we can read the number using the "%d".

Answer (score 1):

The format of your string is not just one number. If you want to just read the age, include the  header and put the following above your fscanf statement.

```
int ch=0;
while(((ch=fgetc(stream)))!=EOF && !isdigit(ch)){}
ungetc(ch,stream);
```

Comment: To work correctly, you need to make `ch` an `int`, not a `char`, and you need to change your while loop to something like: `while (EOF != (ch=fgetc(stream)) && !isdigit((unsigned char)ch))`

Comment: Buggy code. Never store the result of `fgetc` in a `char` because you lose the ability to detect `EOF` return. Always use `int`. Notice your code will loop forever if it hits `EOF` without finding any digits.